# DMin in VBA returns wrong value from query

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

im trying to use vba in an access project of mine but when I use the DMin function to find the smallest value in a query I instead get the current value of the form I have created returned.

The Dmin function does work correctly when I run it outside the context of the code but I get the problem I described above when I try to use it in my code.

I cant seem to understand the formatting on StackExchange so here is a pastebin of the code instead.

http://pastebin.com/XCNPfNYG

The problem line is here

```
PastPrice = DMin([Price Each], "qryBoxHistory", "[CalConcatID] = 133377")
```

---

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Save_Click()

Dim CurrentConcat As String
Dim PastConcat As String
Dim PastConcatGrab As Boolean
Dim txtbox As String


Dim PastPrice As Currency
Dim ExpPrice As Currency


CurrentConcat = Me!CurrentConcat 'Set current Concatenated ID to the ID on the form

PastConcatGrab = IsNull(DLookup("[CalConcatID]", "qryBoxHistory", "[CalConcatID] = CurrentConcat"))

    If PastConcatGrab = True Then 'If lookup shows that no boxes have been entered under that ID then a message is displayed and the values saved
        txtbox = MsgBox("This is a new box, no past prices exist", vbOKOnly, "Information")
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
    Else
        PastConcat = DLookup("[CalConcatID]", "qryBoxHistory", "[CalConcatID] = CurrentConcat")
        PastPrice = DMin([qryBoxHistory]![Price Each], "qryBoxHistory", "[CalConcatID] = 133377")
        ExpPrice = Me![Price]
        If ExpPrice > PastPrice Then
            txtbox = MsgBox("This Box is not being supplied at a discounted rate, box has NOT been saved", vbOKOnly, "Information")
        Else
            txtbox = MsgBox("This box is discounted, This price has been saved", vbOKOnly, "Information")
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: DMin is a domain aggregate function and will return the minimum value of the selected field (column) for the selected domain (table or query) within the chosen restrictions (where statement). What do you wish to do?

Comment: I wish to get the smallest value from "Price Each" in the query "qryBoxHistory" where the field "CalConcatID" equals the arbitrary value I set for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing the necessary quotes:

```
 DMin("[Price Each]", "qryBoxHistory", "[CalConcatID] = 133377"
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple like that.